# visualization clusterization results

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, cluster-analysis, k-means

After using k-means i have 3 clusters. 
I've used 10 features (marks) in k-means for this data set.

I'm understand that we can't draw 10D chart, but how can i visualize this clusters?
Should i separate data by 2 or 3 features instead 10? 
What axises should i use in my case?

For drawing i'm using js and highcharts.js on client side.

Example of code (just for stackoverflow requirement), but I have 10 coordinates for every point

```
const kmeans = require('ml-kmeans');

let data = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1.5, 1, 1]];

let centers = [[1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1]];


let ans = kmeans(data, 2, { initialization: centers });

console.log(ans);

/*KMeansResult*/

{
  clusters: [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ] 

  centroids: 
   [ { centroid: [ 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1 ], error: 0.25, size: 2 },
     { centroid: [ -1, -1, -1.25, 1, 1 ], error: 0.0625, size: 2 } ],
  converged: true, iterations: 1
}
*/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite generic visualization approach. Clusterings do not have very special requirements.

E.g.

- Scatterplot matrix
- Dimensionality reduction with PCA
- tSNE embeddings
- MDS
- UMAP
- Boxplots
- Violin plots
- ...